# restore data with flushed ntfs

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, data-recovery

We talk about HDD with single NTFS partition with size about 650Gigabytes.

We've done following:

1. delete partition scheme i.e. 512Kilobytes from the beginning;
2. flush 50Gigabytes with \xff from the beginning during write test;
3. restore partition scheme i.e. load mbr backup.

The question: How can we restore NTFS in that case?

What we tried to do:

testdisk with deep search without any found NTFS.

Additional info:

1. `NTFS Boot Sector |Master File Table | File System Data | Master File Table Copy`
2. To prevent the MFT from becoming fragmented, NTFS reserves 12.5 percent of volume by default for exclusive use of the MFT.
3. `50G > 12.5% * 650G`, therefore we cleaned vital data for ntfs recovery capability.

Comment: If you want to recover the data for which NTFS file records still exist, [you can use RecuperaBit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37578411/1101509). **Disclaimer:** I am the developer. BTW your question is OT here unless you are asking how to write a program to do that.

Comment: I've decided to not recover the data from that partition and 've started to use ext4fs partition instead of that corrupted ntfs partition.